# Prestashop 1.5.6 creating a custom page with the top menu but without the left/right blocks

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to create a custom page for Prestashop 1.5.6 which contains only the top menu (I need the left and right blocks not to be there) so I'm not using the CMS. I tried creating a php file and including the header.php and config file, but doing this also adds the left/right blocks . So I went to try to copy the structure of the 404.php file, created the controllers etc. but I get that the custom class controller is not found in "classes/controller/Controller.php" .

So basically I'm looking for a way to create a custom page in Prestashop 1.5.6 with the top menu and without the left/right blocks

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a good way. Create: CustpageController.php.

class CustpageController extends FrontController{

```
public function init(){

    parent::init();
}

public function initContent(){

$this->display_column_left = false;
$this->display_column_right = false;
$this->display_header = false;
$this->display_footer = false;

    parent::initContent();

$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'vat.tpl');
}
```

}
And also create vat.tpl file in your theme dir. Check initContent function - here you can choose what to show :)

Good luck!